# Logic error while implementing leap year in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data

 msg db 'Enter a year ' , 10

    msglen equ $-msg

    leapYear db ' is a leap year.', 10
    leapYearLenght equ $-leapYear
    noLeapYear db ' is not a leap year.', 10 
    noLeapYearLenght equ $-noLeapYear
section .bss

    year resd 1

section .text

    global main

main:

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, msglen
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3 
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, year   
    mov edx, 4  
    int 0x80    

    mov eax, 4  
    mov ebx, 1  
    int 0x80    

    mov edx, 0  
    mov eax, ecx    
    mov ebx, 4h   
    div ebx         ; step 3
    mov eax, edx
    cmp eax, 0  
    jne NoLeapYear
    je L1

L1: 
    mov edx, 0  

    mov eax, ecx    

    mov ebx, 64h    

    div ebx     ; step 2

    mov eax, edx

    cmp eax, 0   

    je L2

    jne LeapYear

L2: 

    mov edx, 0 

    mov eax, ecx    

    mov ebx, 190h

    div ebx     ;step 1

    mov eax, edx

    cmp eax, 0  

    je LeapYear     

    jne NoLeapYear

LeapYear:               ; step4

    mov eax, 4      

    mov ebx, 1     

    mov ecx, leapYear   

    mov edx, leapYearLenght 

    int 0x80      

    jmp Exit        

NoLeapYear:         ; step 5

    mov eax, 4          

    mov ebx, 1          

    mov ecx, noLeapYear     

    mov edx, noLeapYearLenght   

    int 0x80            

    jmp Exit            
Exit:

    mov eax, 1  

    mov ebx, 0  

    int 0x80
```

I have attached my code above. For, every input I give say 1993 the output is a leap year.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to load `year` into `ecx` and you forgot to convert it into a number from text. You also didn't use a debugger. PS: As a courtesy to others, please take care to use proper formatting. If you see it come out broken, fix it by editing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have loaded year into eac, but I did not find any change in the output. I did not understand about converting text into number. Where do you want me to put it because I have seen couple of programs which works without changing text to number@Jester